# Html table with Row lines hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

The above html data provides a table which has corresponding rows and columns.   I want a format in which lines between rows should be hidden only column lines and table border lines should be visible . Hope my question is clear now . I want to create a table where lines between rows should be hidden

Comment: What you saying is not clear and please post your code, just whatever you have, create demo here [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Hi Are u not able to see the screenshot

Comment: No , post a bigger one. and show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the css properties `border` and `border-collapse` on your table tag and set the right border for your td.

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> a </td>
    <td> b </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> c </td>
    <td> d </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following css:

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/uf37xzqh/3/

**HTML**

```
<table id="thetable">
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#thetable {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    background: lightgray;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#thetable td{
    border-right: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table frame="box" rules="cols">
   <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Frankly speaking I tried to give answer the way I know to solve it nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

try this

[JsFieddle](http://jsfiddle.net/619zrff5/3/)

HTML

```
   <table style='border:solid'  cellpadding="10"  cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
td{border-right:solid}
```